# Texture grayscale in libgdx

Tags: android, textures, libgdx, grayscale

Is there a way to transform a libgdx's Texture to a grayscale image? So far I had duplicate the images that I want to grayscale and I did it manually, but I think it is not the best solution because my game is using more and more images and it uses a lot of disk space.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to write a GLSL shader that renders a texture in grayscale.  This requires OpenGL 2.x, and doesn't really "transform" a texture, but just renders it to the display as grayscale.

For a detailed tutorial on shaders that includes a grayscale shader check out:  https://github.com/mattdesl/lwjgl-basics/wiki/ShaderLesson3

(Libgdx doesn't really define the GLSL shader API, that's passed through from OpenGL, so most tutorials or code you find on the web for regular OpenGL should work.)

For a more direct hack, just take [the Libgdx `SpriteBatch` shader](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/SpriteBatch.java#L181) and change the fragment shader so it averages the `rgb` components.  (You can define your own `ShaderProgram` and provide it to a `SpriteBatch` to use.)
Change body of the fragment shader to something like this (untested, so may not compile):

```
+ "  vec4 c = v_color * texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords);\n" //
+ "  float grey = (c.r + c.g + c.b) / 3.0;\n" //
+ "  gl_FragColor = vec4(grey, grey, grey, c.a);\n" //
```

Answer (score 10):

Thought I'd share this for anyone wanting to use some copy/paste code.

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShaderProgram;

public class GrayscaleShader {
    static String vertexShader = "attribute vec4 a_position;\n" +
            "attribute vec4 a_color;\n" +
            "attribute vec2 a_texCoord0;\n" +
            "\n" +
            "uniform mat4 u_projTrans;\n" +
            "\n" +
            "varying vec4 v_color;\n" +
            "varying vec2 v_texCoords;\n" +
            "\n" +
            "void main() {\n" +
            "    v_color = a_color;\n" +
            "    v_texCoords = a_texCoord0;\n" +
            "    gl_Position = u_projTrans * a_position;\n" +
            "}";

    static String fragmentShader = "#ifdef GL_ES\n" +
            "    precision mediump float;\n" +
            "#endif\n" +
            "\n" +
            "varying vec4 v_color;\n" +
            "varying vec2 v_texCoords;\n" +
            "uniform sampler2D u_texture;\n" +
            "\n" +
            "void main() {\n" +
            "  vec4 c = v_color * texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords);\n" +
            "  float grey = (c.r + c.g + c.b) / 3.0;\n" +
            "  gl_FragColor = vec4(grey, grey, grey, c.a);\n" +
            "}";

    public static ShaderProgram grayscaleShader = new ShaderProgram(vertexShader,
            fragmentShader);
}
```

To use it call

```
spriteBatch.setShader(GrayscaleShader.grayscaleShader)
```

And when you're done with grayscale don't forget to call

```
spriteBatch.setShader(null);
```

Comment: You should really put shaders in a seperate file and load them in (and use some neat shader tools), if you want a maintainability readability nightmare choose this option.

Comment: @iLoveUnicorns Agreed. But that's not a copy/paste option for someone wanting a quick solution to play with and test. This doesn't prevent them from doing that, it's just a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

You can load up textures as luminance only, or luminance and alpha in GLES (see [glTexImage2D](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/glTexImage2D.xml)). In libgdx you can specify [PixFormat.Intensity](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Pixmap.Format.html#Intensity) (luminance) or [LuminanceAlpha](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Pixmap.Format.html#LuminanceAlpha) (luminance and alpha) when instantiating the [Texture](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Texture.html#Texture%28com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle,%20com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.Format,%20boolean%29). This will generate a grayscale texture.

You still need to have two textures (one color, one grayscale) loaded up, but they can use the same source, and the luminance only uses only 1 byte per pixel in memory.
A more efficient solution is to implement a shader as suggested by P.T., but is only available from GLES 2.